# Recruiter doesn't get back to me until I email her, then gives me an unconvincing response

Tags: recruitment, internship

A little annoyed and not sure how to move forward, so any advice is appreciated.

I applied to a large tech company over two months ago for an internship by giving my resume to the recruiter when she came to my university. The recruiter came back, I think, two more times between September and now and I chatted with her all those times while she kept on reminding me that interviews for the program would take place in mid-November.

For the next month, I see some people I know start getting interviews for the program, so I touch base with the recruiter again and she reiterates that these are special cases and that the process will happen in mid-November.

Well, mid-November rolls through so I email her again and I get a response saying that they've concluded interviews for my University for the Fall and that they'll be back in the Spring (untrue, the recruiting for this program ends before December).

And now, I'm really annoyed. It seems like I wasn't going to hear anything back unless I reached out to the recruiter and now after this entire semester, I'm not even getting an interview it seems for a program that I am pretty qualified for (and got an interview for last year, as a freshman).

The person who interviewed me for the program last year asked me to keep in touch (she's now higher up in recruiting), so could I email her with my concerns (or not even, just say I want to catch up and am interested in re-applying)? Or should I email the current recruiter with an explanation of my frustration with this process?

Comment: Put your energy in trying to get an other internship.

Comment: For whatever reason, they did not think you were competitive this year. (Last year is irrelevant. Different people appied this year and you may be weaker in comparison to them or different people may be evaluationg the applications and be looking for something other than what you have.) They chose not to interview you. Companies virtually never get back to people they choose not to interview. There is no point in getting upset about this, simply move on to the next possibility. You shouldn't be waiting on one possibility anyway, never conclude a job search until the job is in hand.

Answer (score 4):

So you interviewed last year, I assume you didn't get the internship, tried again this year and got no reply (apart from the multiple times you contacted the recruiter)?

> And now, I'm really annoyed. It seems like I wasn't going to hear anything back unless I reached out to the recruiter

Get used to it, it'll happen multiple times during your career.  Sounds like the recruiter chickened out of laying it straight and fobbed you off with excuses.

I'd say as a hiring manager that you weren't what they were looking for, could be multiple reasons, from the info in your application to how you followed it up or even how you did at the last interview, I couldn't say from your description, but it happens to the best of us.

I'd move on, keep trying other internships, may be worth giving it a try in the spring again (maybe it will happen and she isn't spinning you a line), but have a look at the applications your friends who did get interviews made to see if they did something different/better than you.

But don't pester last years recruiter or this year's, you will get yourself filed in the "no thanks" pile permanently.